# How to submit job(jar) to the Azure Spark cluster through commandline interface?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-cli

I am new to HDInsight Spark, I am trying to run a use-case to learn how things work in Azure Spark cluster. This is what I have done so far.

1. Able to create azure spark cluster.
2. Create jar by following steps as described in the link: [create standalone scala application to run on HDInsight Spark cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-create-standalone-application/#create-a-standalone-scala-project). I have used the same scala code as given in the link.
3. ssh into head node
4. upload jar to the blob storage using link: [using azure CLI with azure storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/)
5. copy zip to machine
   hadoop fs -copyToLocal

I have checked that the jar gets uploaded to the headnode(machine).
I want to run that jar and get the results as stated in the link given in 
point 2 above.
What will be the next step? How can I submit spark job and get results using command line interface?

Answer (score 2):

For example considering you are created jar for program submit.jar. In order to submit this to your cluster with dependency you can use below syntax.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --packages "com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.2.5" --class com.ex.abc.MainMethod "wasb://space-hdfs@yourblob.blob.core.windows.net/xx/xx/submit.jar" "param1.json" "param2"
```

Here --packages :is to include dependency to you program, you can use --jars option and then followed by jar path. `--jars "path/to/dependency/abc.jar"`

--class : Main method of your program
after that specify path for your program jar.
you can pass parameters with if you needed as shown above

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options on submitting spark jars:

1) If you want to submit the job on the headnode already, you can use spark-submit
See [Apache submit jar documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

2) An easier alternative is to submit spark jar via livy after uploading the jar to wasb storage. 
See [submit via livy doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-livy-rest-interface/). You can skip step 5 if you do it this way.

Comment: 2) not working at all. Microsoft really should make its tutorial meaningful.